# Cannot switch gcc version

Tags: gcc, bazel

On a Ubuntu 16.04.2 I am trying to compile code with a newer gcc.

So I did the following:

1. in the workspace create a file `tools/cpp/CROSSTOOL`
2. copy latest CROSSTOOL content from bazel repo into that
3. in CROSSTOOL file, under identifier `local_linux`, change `/usr/bin/gcc` to `/usr/bin/gcc-7`
4. Call `bazel build //foo`

When I output the commandline executed to build `//foo:foo`, it calls `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Setting `CC` environment does work but I do not want to have to remember to have that in my environment.

Comment: Interestingly it indeed seems like it uses `CC` over CROSSTOOL!?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using static crosstool that is only used for bootstrapping and some tests (and some other details). What bazel usually uses is tools/cpp/CROSSTOOL.tpl which is a template populated by tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl. This is the script that inspects CC environment variable and if set, it uses that for gcc.

Of course you can use static crosstool, you just have to tell bazel about it using `--crosstool_top=//some/crosstool` flag. You can save it in a project local `.bazelrc`.